# using the values of rendered datatable in later analysis

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

When an object is created using DT::renderDataTable ( I need use DT::, because I modify the original table by adding rows), say "myTable", can this object be used in later analysis? To be more clear, is there an input$myTable or a myTable() command which gives me the modified table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DT package you can create a proxy object of a table using [dataTableProxy()](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html). But the manipulation of the proxy seems to be focused on (un)selection of rows. So you can access the index of rows selected and such, but not the information inside the table. At least not directly.

One way to go around this is to modify the original table inside a reactive(), and then call it in the renderDataTable(). So later on, you can call the table inside the reactive.

Comment: 1) created a data.frame (df) in a reactive value (r$df)
2) insert an actionbutton
2) the actionbutton launches an observeEvent, where the row was added to the data.frame
3) renderDataTable(datatable(data.frame)) to make it visible in the ui
4) the result can be viewed in r$df